# Search in a .csv file with a php script for a value

Tags: php, csv

I'm currently struggling to output some data from a .csv file with a php script.

I have a number given as $number1 and I need to search the file numbers.csv for the number in the variable $number1. If the file contains the number, it should prompt out the content from the line where the $number1 is located.

That's how I solved it:

```
<?php
$number = '1234';

$handle = fopen ('test.csv','r');

while (($csv_array = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE ) {

if (in_array($chip, $csv_array))
{
 echo $csv_array[1];
} else {
echo 'No match';
}
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgetcsv to parse a CSV file without having to worry about parsing it yourself.

Example from PHP Manual:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```